# Classification vs Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification

I am not quite sure what the differences are between classification and regression.

From what I understand is that classification is something that is categorical. It's either this or it's either that.

Regression is more of a prediction.

[image]

[image]

Both of the problems above would be more of a Regression problem right? It is both using a learning algorithm to predict. Could anyone give an example of Classification vs Regression?

Comment: Please find the answer to this question here:- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/69524/81999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: given some data point, classification assigns a label (or 'class') to that point.  This label is, as you said, categorical.  One example might be, say, malware classification: given some file, is it malware or is it not?  (The "label" will be the answer to this question: 'yes' or 'no'.)

But in regression, the goal is instead to predict a real value (i.e. not categorical).  An example here might be, given someone's height and age, predict their weight.

So in either of the questions you've quoted, the answer comes down to what you are trying to get out of your prediction: a category, or a real value?

(A side note: there are connections and relations between the two problems, and you could, if you wanted, see regression as an extension of classification in the case where the labels are ordinal and there are infinite labels.)

Comment: Great description. See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification

Answer (score 1):

1.**Classification** is a process of organizing data into categories for its most effective and efficient use whereas **Regression** is the process of identifying the relationship and the effect of this relationship on the outcome of the future value of object.
2.classification is used to predict both numerical and categorical data whereas regression is used to predict numerical data.

Answer (score 0):

**Classification examples**:-

Predicting whether a share of a company is good to buy or no given that the previous history of the company, along with the buyer's review on it saying yes or no for buying the share. **(Discrete answer: Buy - Yes/No)**

**Regression example**:-

Predicting the best price at which one should buy the share of a company given that the previous history of the company, along with the buyer's review of the price at which they bought the share in the past. **(Continuous answer:- Price range)**

Answer (score 0):

As i Understood Just A simple Example

imagine Data WIll predict us dollar price based on past year & Amount

Regression - IF You want to predict
**How much Price** will go Up of Us Dollar than Euro based on past year & Amount than
its Procces of Regression where Have to predict continues numberic output

but in
Classification  - If You Want To predict **The Price Will go Up of Us Dollare than Euro "Yes Or no"** Than In this case where Classification Comes in

in simple words it Used for predict cateforical output true/false or yes/no